# mySQL query returns only one result

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to get each row in a table to appear as part of a survey.  The following code is returning only the first row in the table (so users can see only one question).  I've been over and over this and can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Would much appreciate any input.

Thank you!

```
function getQuestions ($dbc) <!--$dbc=database connection-->  {
$query = "SELECT * FROM survey_questions" <!--survey_questions=table-->  ;
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) )  {
    $body = $row ['question_body'] <!--question_body=row in table-->  ;

        echo '
            <div class="entry">  <!--user entry form-->
            <h3 class="qTitle">'.$body.'</h3>
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="answer" size="85" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="questionid" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
                </form>
            </div> 
        ';

}
```

}

Comment: A. You must not use `@` for PHP commands. B. Does the table have more results in it? C. What does `mysqli_num_rows()` give?

Comment: 1) Does your table actually have multiple rows?  2) Look at the output HTML page source.  Does the second loop contain something which breaks the output on screen because it is unescaped? (should use `htmlspecialchars($body)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to echo so much using php...

You have to use `//` or `/* */` to comment in PHP and not `<!---->` cuz that's for HTML

Secondly coming to your code..

Why you are using?

```
function getQuestions($dbc) //I dont know what this is doing here, why you are wrapping your code in a function???
```

you can simply write like this (use echo to print out your question):

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM survey_questions");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result) )  {
        ?>
   <div class="entry">  <!--user entry form-->
      <h3 class="qTitle"><?php echo $row['whatever']; ?></h3>
          <form action="index.php" method="post">
             <input type="text" name="answer" size="85" />
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
             <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="questionid" />
             <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
          </form>
   </div> 
<?php
     }
?>
```

Comment: @The DOCTOR from TARDIS, mysqli_num_rows() is 2.  There are two rows in the table.  I took out the @ (thank you).  Still not getting a good result.

Comment: It's used in a couple of different spots in the HTML.

Comment: @rebaelliott What do you mean by different spots in html? I recommend you to study how functions work

Comment: thanks but I'm not getting a good result with this code.  Probably my fault with formatting.  Working through the errors now.

Comment: @rebaelliott did you changed `$row['whatever'];` to appropriate field?

Comment: thank you.  Maybe I should make myself clearer.  I will use this block of code on this page and one or two others.  I thought it would be easier to call to a function rather than type in the block each time.

Answer (score 0):

The results are now two entry forms (an improvement) but still not displaying the text of the two rows from the database.  Instead of the row text, I get the > character where the text should be.  Here is the updated code, adapting the suggestion of @Mr. Alien:

```
function getQuestions($dbc) {

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM survey_questions");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result) )  {
         echo ' 
              <div class="entry">  
              <h3 class="qTitle">'. $row['survey_questions'].'></h3>
                   <form action="index.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="answer" size="85" >
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="questionid" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" >
                  </form>
             </div> 
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting the '>' character because there is an extra one right before your closing </h3> tag.  Also, in the above example in your output HTML, you used $row['survey_questions'] - shouldn't that be $row['question_body']?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, @Ray, for pointing out these errors.  Working beautifully now.  Thanks a lot.